# Why do they show unrelated lines at the beginning of the movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, raman-raghav-2.0

In Raman Raghav 2.0, The movie starts with these lines which tell a killer's story.

[image]

And then this line appears it and says "This film not about him".

[image]

Then why do they show unrelated lines at the beginning of the movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it was not so unrelated. The film's killer was based on the [real life killer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_Raghav) and even Anurag Kashyap originally wanted to make the film on real killer only:

> Kashyap told that him that he'd wanted to make a film on the notorious Raman Raghav, infamously known as Psycho Raman, but the budget constraints did not allow him to make a period film set in the '60s. Even the title of the film Raman Raghav 2.0 came into the picture even before the script was ready. -  [scoopwhoop.com](https://www.scoopwhoop.com/How-Anurag-Kashyap-Made-Raman-Raghav-20-With-A-Shoestring-Budget-Will-Leave-You-Awestruck/#.woaq96p2i)

So due to money issue they made it set in current setting and made the killer fictional. Even film's killer Ramanna acknowledged the real life killer.